# How do I handle textures for a 2d opengl project?

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, game-engine

I want to make a small 2D game in C++. I need to know how to actually render the game. I understand the basics behind opengl, you load vertices into an vbo, load the textures into a vbo and then you can use a draw call using a shader to interpret it. But how do I actually do it in 2D. Do I really only need a vbo storing a single square, and then all the textures, with which I use gltransform to change based on the details of the sprite I am rendering? How do I actually reference the texture I need for the sprite if it is all in one big vbo?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to implement this yourself? There are a lot of free libraries out there that do this for you, and are quite good at it (e.g. [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org), [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org), [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org) etc.).

If you're worried about performance issues or something along those lines, then stop, because you're most likely wrong.

If, however, you want to learn how it's done, then by all means do it... but it's still a good idea to install one of these free open source libraries and look at their source code, as it's been in use (in production!) for quite some time now.

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, sorry if it doesn't help you.